# Is there a way to know the structure and code of lamda provided by aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am using aws-sagemaker. Follow the workflow and provide by aws during use
You are trying to use Lambda with
`arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:454466003867:function:PRE-ImageMultiClass`
ARN.

But I want to know the structure and code of this Lambda function before I use it, and I also want to customize it.
What I want to do is pre-processing and post-processing of the Ground Trust custom labeling tool. But I want to know the structure of the Lambda function described earlier.
Do you have any Aws Docs or examples that I can tell you my questions?

Comment: There are part of the service deployment and I think you will not be able to get the source for it. One way to customize is to write your own pre and post lambda - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates-step3.html